# Standard deviation of error from leave one out

Tags: standard-deviation, cross-validation

I have a classification process which I test using leave-one-out.

Precisely, how do I compute the standard deviation of the result?

If I compute it normally, I get a very large deviation which makes sense because each test is either 100% or 0%.

What is the accepted convention in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your error function? Are you using misclassification rate?

Comment: well, I wanted the variance of the correct %.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking how the determine the variance of the misclassification rate for all of N-fold cross validations? Or are you asking about the expected misclassification rate for your selected model?

Comment: I want to determine the variance of the misclassification rate. If I'm doing a regular N-fold cross validation, then I will a vector of mis-classification rates and then I can just compute the variance. With leave-one-out that vector contains only 100 and 0, so the variance is very large. I'm assuming there is something else for loo.

Comment: There is no problem in estimating the variance of a Bernoulli random variable. As long as your estimated variance is less than or equal to 50*50 what's wrong with having a large variance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you can't, unless you make some simple significance test to check if it is better than random guessing.

Anyway, you can still use stochastic or N-fold CV to get more continuous error scale; or, supposing that your algorithm is stochastic, just aggregate several LOO results with different random seeds.

Comment: what do you mean several LOO with different random seeds? there's nothing random about loo since it goes over all samples. thanks.

Comment: Your learning algorithm may be stochastic -- random forest for instance.

Comment: @mbq, thanks -- as having the same problem -- this might be **a really newbie question**: but still, I'm puzzled by your answer. if you further explain your answer it could be great. , (1) what you mean by "simple significance test to check if it is better than random guessing." ? (2) why stochastic assumption is related to this & how/why it can help here ? thanks in advance

Comment: @Dov (1) Something like what fraction of randomly shuffled versions of decision obtain better accuracy (or its parametric version). (2) If you make N LOOs of the same deterministic algorithm, the sd of results will be zero and useless; in case of stochastic one, this will be some approximation of uncertainty of mean error.